# How can I migrate oracle rds database to mariadb in rds

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, schema, database-migration

I am confused with schema conversion tool i cannot see target as mariadb . I want to migrate oracle database in ec2 instance to rds mariadb or mariadb ec2 instance. Please help me to get some idea.

Answer (score 1):

The SCT doesn't support Oracle to Maria ([reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/SchemaConversionTool/latest/userguide/Welcome.html) showing supported source-targets).

For migrating from an Oracle EC2 to a MariaDB EC2, have you seen [this](http://www.sqlines.com/sqldata/oracle-to-mariadb)?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So there is no possiblity to migrate to rds mariadb??

Comment: There is, just not using the Schema Conversion Tool. You can migrate using http://www.sqlines.com/sqldata/oracle-to-mariadb

Answer (score 0):

You can migrate oracle database to MariaDB 10.2 and 10.3 now. Reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/SchemaConversionTool/latest/userguide/CHAP_Welcome.html